# How to prevent flash audio mode for chrome with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flash, sdk, soundmanager2

There is a Chrome bug from the version 49

This is affecting my application which is based on this api http://soundcloud.lrdiv.co/ ( github repo https://github.com/lrdiv/ember-soundcloud )

Basically the problem is that Soundcloud Api uses soundmanager2 as a base to handle audio stream that itself have 2 modes flash and html5. The issue is that if the flash player is available it will try to use it and fail while if it's not available it will just use html5 and work right away.

Proof is that if you go here *chrome://plugins/* and deactivate the flash player the audio stream will work again in Chrome.

In this discussion https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/issues/39#issuecomment-206726301 , one possible temporary hack is to detect chrome and return false for playing in flash mode.

```
    function d() {
        var t, e, n, i;
        if ("undefined" != typeof window.ActiveXObject)
            try {
                i = new window.ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash"),
                i && (t = i.GetVariable("$version"))
            } catch (r) {}
        else
            window.navigator && window.navigator.plugins && window.navigator.plugins.length > 0 && (n = "application/x-shockwave-flash",
            e = window.navigator.mimeTypes,
            e && e[n] && e[n].enabledPlugin && e[n].enabledPlugin.description && (t = e[n].enabledPlugin.description));
        // @todo, chrome flash player bug, if under chrome, dont return true here, more info:
        // https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/issues/39
        **if (!!window.chrome) {
          return false
        }**
        return t

    }
```

I would like to do the same in my [sdk.js](https://jsfiddle.net/Manna/p4wbmy85/) but not very clear in which line i have i have to prevent the flash streaming for chrome

Comment: Why not just use the official SoundCloud API? Then you can choose by yourself whether Flash plugin or HTML5 is used...

Comment: Soundcloud Api uses soundmanager2 as a base to handle audio stream

Comment: "...the problem is that Soundcloud Api uses soundmanager2" where is this mentioned in the official API?. Maybe it was true a few years ago. What is that Irdiv API doing that you really can't achieve with current official SoundCloud API anyway? Just try it for one day. It's easy.

Comment: Yes what i have tried is when i select or play a song to detect navigator.plugins['Shockwave Flash']; and return false. https://jsfiddle.net/r27rayLv/1/  but it seems not correct, my music player breaks then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my sdk.js i had to add

```
soundManager.preferFlash = false;
```

to not use Flash Plugin as Audio Player